# Как читать из файла и хранить при этом часть прочитанного в памяти?

Tags: c++, linux

Стоит такая задача. Есть большой файл, его надо прочитать посимвольно. При этом, надо постоянно держать в памяти последние несколько прочитанных символов.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using std::vector, std::ios, std::ifstream;

int main() {
    ifstream fIle;
    fIle.open("myfile.bin", ios::in|ios::binary);
    char ch;
    vector<char> chm(8);
    while(fIle.get(ch)) {
        // и тут я запутался
    }
```

Вот как наиболее адекватно реализовать такое? Читать кусками по 8 байт - нельзя! Надо читать строго по байту и при этом держать последние 8 прочитанных байт, в т ч только что прочитанный, в памяти...

Comment: Если файл действительно большой, то читатььего надо через `mmap()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл более интуитивно понятный ответ:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using std::vector, std::ios, std::ifstream;

int main() {
    ifstream fIle;
    fIle.open("myfile.bin", ios::in|ios::binary);
    char ch;
    vector<char> chm(8);
    for (unsigned int k=0; k < chm.size(); k++) {
        chm[k] = ' '; // инициализируем пустой вектор
    }
    while(fIle.get(ch)) {
        for (unsigned int j=7; j > 0; j--) {
            chm[j-1] = chm[j]; // сдвигаем символы
        }
        chm[7] = ch;
    }
```

Comment: Он-то понятный, только ради чего каждый раз двигать все символы? ладно, когда их 8, а если 800? :)

Comment: хм, а вот тут действительно интересно...

Comment: Вы символы [не стой стороны сдвигаете](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6352b6e25ea8b86c).

Answer (score 5):

Ну читайте как в циклический буфер...

```
for(int k = 0; fIle.get(chm[k]); k = (k+1)%8) 
{
    // Тут делайте, что хотите :) 
    // i-й символ (считая с 1; только что введенный - 8-й)
    // находится в chm[(k+i)%8]
}
```